# View not recognising model attributes? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it so that this form here will display certain fields based on the type of the website. In this case, I want it to display the form for when project.type == Website.

However I keep getting

```
undefined method `type' for #<Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffe1cb543a8>
```

I am sure i can call .type normally because it works in the console.

Here are my files:

```
#views/assets/_new_asset.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @asset do |f| %>
<% if @project.type == 'Website' %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :url %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my assets/controller

```
#controller/assets_controller.rb
class AssetsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @asset = Asset.new
        project = Asset.where(:project_id)
        @project = Project.where(:id == project)
        end


    def create
        @asset = current_user.assets.build(asset_params)

    if @asset.save
      flash[:notice] = "Asset successfully added."
      redirect_to(@project, :action => 'show')
    else
      render(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  private

  def asset_params
    params.require(:asset).permit(:id, :type,:url, :page_rank, :rev_company ,:social_pages)
  end



end
```

Comment: Try giving like this `<% if @project.first.type == 'Website' %>`

Comment: I think your @project is a collection of projects, you need to loop it over and then look for its type

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are getting back an object of **`ActiveRecord::Relation`**, not your **`model instance`**, thus the error since there is no method called **`type`** in **`ActiveRecord::Relation`**.

This should work

```
@project = Project.where(:id == project).first
```

**OR**

You can do like this too

```
<% if @project.first.type == 'Website' %>
```

Doing **`@project.first.type`** works because **`@project.first`** is returning the first instance of the model that was found by the **`where`**

Comment: I tried this but its not working for some reason and is rather giving me the else part of the statement. Do you have any other ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

```
#views/assets/_new_asset.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @asset do |f| %>
     <% if (@project.type == 'Website') %>
     <%= f.input :name %>
     <%= f.input :url %>
     <%= f.button :submit %>
     <% else %>
     You Should not see this line. 
<% end %>
```

In Controller

```
#controller/assets_controller.rb
class AssetsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @asset = Asset.new
        # As if i have no idea from where youre getting :project_id
        # in your code so i changed that. add that to asset_params
        # if required. Thanks!!!
        @project = Project.where(id: params[:project_id]).take
    end

    def create
        @asset = current_user.assets.build(asset_params)

       if @asset.save
        flash[:notice] = "Asset successfully added."
        redirect_to(@project, :action => 'show')
      else
        render(:action => 'new')
      end
   end

  private

  def asset_params
    params.require(:asset).permit(:id, :type,:url, :page_rank, :rev_company ,:social_pages)
  end

end
```